# Where is the definitive, official specification of the dBase (.dbf) file format?

Tags: dbase

Below is a sample dBase (.dbf) file. I've circled the portion of the file that contains the "language driver".

[image: Language driver field of dBase file]

At this website is a description of the format of dBase files: http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm

First question: is that the definitive, official specification of the format of dBase files or is there some other place that has the definitive, official specification?

That website doesn't say much about the language driver field, it merely says that it is a 32 byte field containing the language driver name. Well, if you examine the above 32 bytes, it appears to have more structure than simply a 32 byte name.

I found another website that seems to divide up the 32 bytes into a number of subfields. Here is the website: http://dbfviewer.com/dbf-file-structure/

Below is a graphic showing how it divides up the 32 bytes. Who do I believe? The website that (I think) has the official specification of the format of dBase files or the website of someone who created a tool to process dBase files?

[image]

Comment: Whom should you believe: What type of DBF file do you have? Clipper? FoxBase? Dbase III, Dbase IV, Visual Dbase 7? It depends.

Comment: It looks like you have a dBase III file (the first byte is `03`), your first link describes the format of dBase 7. Afaik dBase III files have no language driver name, at least the few I inspected had none. Also, the language-driver id (0x0D) is `00`, so I don't think your file specifies a language-driver at all. The structure of the file from 0x20 looks like the Field Subrecord Structure, with `Name` being the name of the first field.